# Laravel google Login with Socialite

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-socialite

I have proble error 404 when i login with google

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nthG.png)

But before that i can choose the email it correctly goes well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS6Rq.png)

This My config/service.php

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Mailgun, Postmark, AWS and more. This file provides the de facto
    | location for this type of information, allowing packages to have
    | a conventional file to locate the various service credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],
    'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'https://hmif-fst.my.id/auth/login/callback',
    ],




];
```

This my routes

```php
Route::get('/auth/login', [GoogleController::class, 'redirectToGoogle'])->name('google.login');
Route::get('/auth/login/callback', [GoogleController::class, 'handleGoogleCallback']);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ynUE.png)

This My Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class GoogleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Google authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        $clientID = config('services.google.client_id');

        // Use $clientID for the desired purpose

        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Google.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handleGoogleCallback(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

            // Check if the user is already registered based on google_id
            $user = User::where('google_id', $googleUser->getId())->first();

            if (!$user) {
                // User is not registered, create a new user with Google account data
                $userData = User::create([
                    'name' => $googleUser->getName(),
                    'email' => $googleUser->getEmail(),
                    'google_id' => $googleUser->getId(),
                    'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
                    'avatar' => $googleUser->getAvatar(), // Save the avatar URL from Google
                ]);
                // Log in the newly created user
                Auth::login($userData);
                return redirect()->intended('/home');
            } else {
                // User is already registered, validate the password
                if ($request->has('password') && !Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
                    throw ValidationException::withMessages(['password' => 'Invalid password']);
                }

                Auth::login($user);
                return redirect()->intended('/home');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle the exception
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => 'Something went wrong. Please try again.']);
        }
    }
}
```

And this my Home Website

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kI3Z.png)

Any Solustion, Thank You

Comment: Are your routes cached? `php artisan route:clear`